# How to print formatted contents of Viewfield in a custom template?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I am having trouble printing the contents of two Viewfields in my custom node template. They are two separate blocks in the same overall View. I have tried the following, but it did not print anything:

```
<?php echo $node->field_fieldname1[0]['view']; ?>
<?php echo $node->field_fieldname2[0]['view']; ?>
```

When I add

```
<?php print_r($node); ?>
```

to my template, it returns the following for the two Viewfields in question:

> [field_fieldname1] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] =>
>   Array ( [vname] => myviewname|block_1 [vargs] => ) ) )
>
> [field_fieldname2] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => 
>   Array ( [vname] => myviewname|block_2 [vargs] => ) ) )

Can anyone direct me on how I can print the contents of these Viewfields in my tpl file?

Thanks!

Comment: What about `print render($node->field_fieldname1)`

Comment: Is it Drupal 6 (seems to be by the structure you used)? And try @Chris's code, it should do the trick

Comment: @Rotem it is for Drupal 7. The code I used above was my "best guess" based on what I could find via Google. I tried Chris's code, and it did not work... nothing showed up on the page.

Comment: Is there a resource online somewhere that shows how such fields should be printed specifically for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('myviewname','block_1', $node->nid); ?>
<?php print views_embed_view('myviewname','block_2', $node->nid); ?>
```

And the view's info is printing just fine now in my tpl files. Hope this can help someone in the future.

Thanks for Worldfallz on the Drupal forum for this suggestion!
https://drupal.org/node/2075411#comment-7800227